# How to specify a date / time offset in days

Tags: datetime, java-8, datetimeoffset

Using Java's date parsing mechanism I'd like to specify a date / time with an offset in days. Basically similar to the timezone offset.

Examples:

- Yesterday: midnight minus 1 day
- Day before yesterday: midnight minus 2 days
- Midday of the day before yesterday: midnight minus 1 day minus
  12 hours
- Starting 1 week ago: midnight minus 1 week

Is that possible and how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think it is possible at the time of the parsing. But still you can do date time manipulations in Java8 after parsing it to a `LocalDateTime` object like so,

```
System.out.println("Tomorrow: " + LocalDateTime.now().plusDays(1));
System.out.println("Yesterday: " + LocalDateTime.now().minusDays(1));
System.out.println("One week ago: " + LocalDateTime.now().minusWeeks(1));
```

You can apply date and time modifications in combination with the [Duration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) class. Example:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME;
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
Duration duration = Duration.parse( "-P1DT15M");

System.out.println( "Duration   : " + duration.toMillis());
System.out.println( "Now        : " + formatter.format( now));
System.out.println( "Now-P1DT15M: " + formatter.format( duration.addTo(now)));
```

results in

```
Duration   : -87300000
Now        : 2018-04-12T08:59:10.91
Now-P1DT15M: 2018-04-11T08:44:10.91
```

Comment: Thank you, that brought me on the right track where to search for. I edited your post and added an example with duration, I hope you don't mind.